# Trouble with animating NSLayoutConstraint while changing intrinsic size

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to orchestrate some animations within a `UIView` subclass that require a change in the intrinsic size of the view.

In the `CATransaction` completion block I call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` to reflect the change in size, and right after I animate my constraints.

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
UIView.animateWithDuration(2) {
  NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(oldConstraints)
  NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(newConstraints)
  self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But a strange thing happens, along with the constraints provided to the `deactivateConstraints` and `activateConstraints` methods, I also see the view's size being animated along the same duration.

Here's a video of this in action.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgM378Wryd0

Here's a diagram of the problem.

[image]

My intention is to change the size of the view immediately, and not animate it along with the positioning constraints.

Comment: why are you using animateWithDuration method if your intention is not to animate?

Comment: My intention is to animate position, not size.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that ends up working is wrapping the initial `layoutIfNeeded()` call in a animation block, and then initiating the position animation on completion.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() }) {
  UIView.animateWithDuration(2) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(oldConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(newConstraints)
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

It doesn't look pretty, since I'm not not actually animating size changes, I want them to happen immediately. So I'm still looking for an elegant solution, or a reason why there can't be one.